# How do i open another file using on-press in react native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, button, react-navigation

how do I open another file using the on-press function, I would like to open a JavaScript file from my home screen in the app, basically, I want to be able to press the button and connect to my other javascript  file from my first touchable-opacity

here is the code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image,ImageBackground,button,  
TouchableOpacity, Dimensions,Button} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator,} from 'react-navigation';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width; 
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { './video1.js' },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
});

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
     <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
 <ImageBackground source={{uri: 'https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/usa_avengers_sb_bkgd8_1024_0ae5b001.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C1024%2C576'}}
    style={{width: width, height: height,}}> 



    <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.spiderman} onPress={() =>
          navigate{'Profile'}>
      <Image source={{uri: 'http://www.pngmart.com/files/2/Spider-Man-Transparent-Background.png'}}
   style={{width: 190, height:250,}} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.panther}>
      <Image source={{uri:
'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/avengers-assemble/images/a/a0/Usa_avengers_herochi_blackpanther_r_e1954416.png/revision/latest?cb=20170417131405'}}
   style={{width: 190, height: 300, }} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.hulk}>
      <Image source={{uri: 'https://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1516942387Hulk-Png-Cartoon.png'}}
   style={{width: 225, height: 350}} />
    </TouchableOpacity>

  </ImageBackground>
  </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: You can use `react-navigation `

Comment: how whats is the setup for react navigate??

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

Comment: it dos not show me how to add a file

Comment: The way you set up is wrong, I suggest looking at examples, because from the code you provided there are a couple of mistakes

Comment: thats what im asking what are the mistakes

Comment: This `const App = StackNavigator({ Home: {'./video1.js' }, Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen }, });` change to const App = createStackNavigator({ Home: { VideoScreen}, Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen }, });`

Comment: do i still add the on-press function after touchable opacity

Comment: it says react navigation does not exist in hast module map or in these directories

Comment: Did you add it in terminal `yarn add react-navigation `

Comment: Thanks it works, now my only issue is getting from one page to the other

Comment: You do this `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate({'Profile'}) `

Comment: idk what the issue is

Comment: <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.video}
      style={styles.spiderman}>
      <Image source={{uri: 'http://www.pngmart.com/files/2/Spider-Man-Transparent-Background.png'}}
   style={{width: 190, height:250,}}/
   >

Comment: const video=[video1.js]

Comment: `this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') `

Comment: I think you should look at a tutorial on how `react-navigation` works